# Kotlin - How can open a csv file via Intent using default apps?

Tags: android, csv, kotlin

My android app flow is as follows:

1. Creates a csv file.
2. Store it in the default app folder.
3. Generates a notification of succesful creation
4. Open the csv in the default app.

I can not be able to open the csv via Intent or other methods so far.

With the following code I'm able to open the explorer but not in the folder path.

```
var path = this.applicationContext.getExternalFilesDir(null)?.absolutePath.toString()
println("Hey my path is $path")
val csvWriter = CSVWriter(
                fileWriter,
                CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR,
                CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER,
                CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,
                CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END
            )
csvWriter.writeAll(data.toMutableList())
csvWriter.close()

val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
                    addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
                    type = "application/*"
                }
startActivityForResult(intent, 2)
```

Also, I tried to develop a function but without effective response:

```
fun open_file(filename: String?) {
        val path = File(filesDir, "dl")
        val file = File(path, filename)

        // Get URI and MIME type of file
        val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "$PACKAGE_NAME.fileprovider", file)
        val mime = contentResolver.getType(uri)

        // Open file with user selected app
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, mime)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

I saw some possible solutions developed in java but there are deprecated and / or does not work converted in Kotlin.

**Edit:**
Given the suggestion of @CommonsWare, I'm trying to save the file in the path given but the user. However, I get the error : **No Activity found to handle Intent**

```
val FILE_EXPORT_REQUEST_CODE = 12
val exportIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT)
exportIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
exportIntent.type = "text/csv"
val uri =  Uri.parse("$path/file.csv")
exportIntent.data = uri
val filename = "file.csv"
exportIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, filename)
startActivityForResult(exportIntent, FILE_EXPORT_REQUEST_CODE)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "With the following code I'm able to open the explorer but not in the folder path" -- that's not really a thing in Android, sorry, at least if you are creating a file directly on the filesystem. "I tried to develop a function but without effective response" -- we do not know what your specific symptoms are. Assuming that you have the manifest and XML metadata set up correctly, what you have there seems fine. However, users do not necessarily have an app that supports that MIME type. So, if you are getting an `ActivityNotFoundException`, I am not surprised.

Comment: "How can open a csv file via Intent using default apps?" -- bear in mind that there are a couple billion Android users, spread over tens of thousands of device models. The roster of pre-installed apps varies by model. Plus, users may be running in restricted profiles and may not have access to all of the pre-installed apps. Even for something as common as HTML, do not assume that all users have access to an activity to view it. For something like CSV... you're welcome to try launching an app for it, but there is a good chance that the user will not have an app for it.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the answers. The path is "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.dafmedinama.myApp/files". When I open the explorer, it show me the general android path but not this. It is possible to open the File explorer in the given path? 

My objective is to (somehow) show where is the CSV file to the user.

Comment: "It is possible to open the File explorer in the given path?" -- no. "My objective is to (somehow) show where is the CSV file to the user" -- then perhaps use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`, and let the user choose where you put the user's content on the user's device (or perhaps in the user's chosen cloud storage provider).

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried but it creates me a empty file or an error. Check my edit please

Comment: Start by getting rid of `exportIntent.data = uri`. The *point* behind `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` is for the *user* to choose where the *user* wants the content to be placed. You use the `Uri` that you get back in `onActivityResult()`, with `ContentResolver` and `openOutputStream()` or `openFileDescriptor()`, to write out the content to the user-chosen location. See [the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#edit).

Comment: See also [this sample Kotlin app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/v1.9/ContentEditor) (covered in [this book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack)) for an example of using `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`, in this case in the context of a tiny text editor.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry but it doesn't work. Trying to save in Downloads folder and got this error :" open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)" even when I have in the Android manifiest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: `intent.setDataAndType(uri, mime)` We have no idea what mime type you would use, especially because we do not know the filename you use. Further you have never told what you consider to be the default app for a csv file. You should use ACTION_VIEW only.

Comment: `With the following code I'm able to open the explorer but not in the folder path.` It can be done with the right code but only for Android 11 devices.